# Auto-login with other account than pi

Tags: login, lightdm

I want to perform autologin with an account "baa_user" at boot, which is in his own group (baa_user) & have his own home folder, without admin rights at all.
I tried almost all solutions that I found but no one worked.
Change file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` worked for pi user with `autologin-user=$MY_USER` (here $MY_USER is one of my user for exemple pi, I didn't write "$MY_USER" in my conf file), not for baa_user...
Don't know what to do :/

Thanks !

Comment: Did you really write `autologin-user=$MY_USER`? I'm surprised to see that .conf files support shell variables.

Comment: No no of course not $MY_USER is one of my user ;) Edit my question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you forgot to add baa_user to the `autologin` group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a baa_user autologin
```

If not, try to login as baa_user manually, maybe you'll find out that something is wrong that prevents the user from starting a desktop session at all.

Comment: Seems it was this !! Thanks, I never thought about it.